# How to serve assets with the webpack 2 dev server

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2

I am trying to serve static files (images) in development via the webpack 2 dev server. I can't seem to make it work. This would be my webpack file, I am serving an Angular 2 app that has images in the folder `/src/assets/images`:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var helpers = require('./helpers');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'app': './src/main.ts',
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loaders: [{
                    loader: 'awesome-typescript-loader',
                    options: { configFileName: helpers.root('src', 'tsconfig.json') }
                } , 'angular2-template-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'html-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
        publicPath: '/assets/'
    },

    plugins: [
        // Workaround for angular/angular#11580
        new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
            // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
            /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
            helpers.root('./src'), // location of your src
            {} // a map of your routes
        ),

        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
            name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
        }),

        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'src/index.html'
        })
    ]
};
```

I see 2 relevant parts here, both do not work:

1. The file-loader that is set to `file-loader?name=assets/[name].[ext]`
2. The `output` field that is set to

   ```
   output: {
       path: path.join(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
       publicPath: '/assets/'
   },
   ```

When I load an image like *http://localhost:8080/assets/images/welt_plus.png* I get a `404`

> Cannot GET /assets/images/welt_plus.png

Comment: I would argue that *for development* you do not need the loader; add a `devServer` section in your `webpack.config.js` and add `src` to the `contentBase` property; e.g.: `devServer: { contentBase: [..., path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')], ... }`. The dev server will be serving files right from your source folder.

Comment: Sorry I did not see your comment, but indeed that was the solution that I found too now. If you post an official answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TL;DR** Customize the dev server in `webpack.config.js` so that it serves the static files, in addition to the built ones. If you are only serving static files(*), you do not even need the file loader. The configuration would be as follows, to serve static files from the `src/` folder, given that `webpack.config.js` is in the project root:

```
module.exports = {
  ...
  devServer: {
    contentBase: [..., path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
    ...
  }
}
```

---

(*) "only serving static" = (1) you do not do `require('assets/images/foo.png')` from your code and (2) your CSS/SCSS does not require any assets either, e.g. does not contain any `url(...)`. It doesn't hurt to leave the file loader though.

---

The longer explanation is that static "asset" files, e.g. the ones used by the application with `<img src="the/static/file.png" />` are NOT processed by the file loader or Webpack. These are requested by the browser and the server is supposed to have them. Webpack deals with "modules", i.e. code and resources requested by `require(...)`, `import ... from ...` etc. The rule in `webpack.config.js` for the file loader says that if some module requires another module with name ending in png, jpeg, ..., then use the file loader.

The configuration above simply instructs the Webpack dev server to serve static files from the given directory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to include your assets in the bundle (so that you can require them like js files)? Or do you want to link to them via urls/links?

If you that they are accessible from within your bundle, try require('./path/to/asset/image.png').

If you want to link to them, you have to set the contentBase correctly, see https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/. The webpack-dev-server will then act as a http-server for that folder (besides serving the bundle of course).

Comment: Thank you, I could find the answer in the dev-server documentation. However I am hesitant to accept your answer (sorry) so people from Google won't be disappointed to not really find the answer.

Answer (score 0):

make sure webpackconfig file is in root, and the following code should work for you. Happy coding.

```
{
  test: /\.png$/,
  include: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'images')
  ],
  use: [{
    loader: 'file-loader',
    options: {
      name: '[path][name].[ext]'
    }
  }]
},
```